# No answer for LyapunovSolve

Tags: wolfram-cloud, wolfram-alpha-notebook-edition

I gave wolfram notebook the code below:

```
f = {{-k,0,0,w,g,0},{0,0,0,g,w,g},{0,0,-k,0,g,w},{-w,-g,0,-k,0,0},{-g,-w,-g,0,0,0},{0,-g,-w,0,0,-k}} ; 
c ={{-m,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,-n,0,0,0},{0,0,0,-m,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,-n}} ;
```

and I want to use LyapunovSolve then I give this:

```
LyapunovSolve[f,c]
```

but the response is

Out = `LyapunovSolve[f,c]`

what is the problem?

Comment: are those variables some numbers!? then substitute in them to find LyapunovSolve

Comment: @Alrubaie I need the answers based on parameters